# Format current date

Tags: optimization, salesforce-apex

I was refactoring some code and found this:

```
DateTime CurrentDateTime = System.now();
Datetime ESTDate = Datetime.newInstance(CurrentDateTime.year(),CurrentDateTime.month(),CurrentDateTime.day(),CurrentDateTime.hour(),CurrentDateTime.minute(),CurrentDateTime.second());
String myDateFormat = ESTDate.format('yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss');
String myDate = myDateFormat.replace(' ', 'T');
object1.birthDate = myDate;
```

And I changed it to

```
object1.birthDate = datetime.now().format('yyyy-MM-dd\'T\'hh:mm:ss');
```

CurrentDateTime isn't used anywhere just in those four lines.
How a programmer can even do that? Or WHY?

Comment: What's language is that?

Comment: @CyrilleKarmann - Probably C# (or other .NET); `DateTime` is the standard 'timestamp' type, and `System.Now` is the 'current timestamp' property.  Personally, though, I'm a little suspicious of anything named `object1`, and storing the _time_ for a birthdate (while technically people _are_ born at a particular 'instant', nobody ever thinks of them that ways - it tends to be the 'local calendar day').  That, and outputting it as a formatted string.  It looks like there may have been an attempt to deal with timezones, but I don't see anything that actually references them, so...

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse no, this is *not* C#. [apex-code](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/apex-code/info) is a programming language for Salesforce.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse imagine that instead birthDate there is a field named f1 -> object1.f1 = ...

Comment: @Chiz - Ouch.  Is there nothing you can do to get better names for things?  I'd be "Spindle, Fold, and Mutilate"-ing someone who tried that on regular production code...

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse it's not real names of variables and fields. It's prohibited for me to show real code. I thought it's obvious. The question is not about NAMES but about excessive number of lines and variables.

Comment: @codesparkle Why not put in a line in the tag wiki to avoid confusion in future?

Comment: I've added descriptions to the apex-code, force.com, and salesforce tags.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The programmer probably didn't understand how quoting works in `DateTime.format()` - just couldn't get the 'T' to appear in the string, so bailed, put the space there and replaced it. Creating `ESTDate` from `CurrentDateTime` is particularly weird, though!